# Minimize expected value from deck of cards containing numbers from 1 to 6.

Tags: probability, expected-value

Part 1: You have infinite cards and on each of them there is written one of the following numbers: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}. You can build a deck in the way you want and after you build it, you need to tell your opponent how many cards of each type you put in the deck. You shuffle the deck. Your opponent will guess a number from 1 to 6 and pick a card at random. If he guesses 1 and picks 1 he wins 1 dollar from you, if he guesses 2 and picks 2 he wins 2 dollars from you, etc. If he does not guess correctly he wins nothing. How would you build a deck so that your opponent wins the least amount of money from you? You know your opponent plays optimally, i.e. he always tries to maximize his profit.

Part 2: How does the answer to the same question change if you need to pay 0.01 dollar for each card you put in the deck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that you took $a_i$ cards with number $i$ written on them, for a total of $a$ cards. Denote $p_i = a_i / a$ — the probability of card with number $i$ ending up on top of the deck after shuffling.

If your opponent guesses $i$ then his expected winnings are $i \cdot p_i$. The only thing he is able to control is $i$, so he maximizes over it and gets $\max\{p_1, 2p_2, \dots, 6p_6\}$ as the result.

As in every other minimax game, your goal now is to minimize this expression over $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_6$. Because $p_i$ have a fixed sum of $1$ it follows that you should choose $$p_1 = 2 p_2 = 3 p_3 = 4 p_4 = 5 p_5 = 6 p_6,$$ and therefore $$a_1 = 2 a_2 = 3 a_3 = 4 a_4 = 5 a_5 = 6 a_6$$ with the minimal integer solution being $a_1 = 60, a_2 = 30, a_3 = 20, a_4 = 15, a_5 = 12, a_6 = 10$, $a = 147$.

The expected winnings of your opponent will then be $\tfrac{60}{147} \approx 0.41$, i.e. 41 cent.

In the second part, however, it may be beneficial to select smth like $a_i' = \left\lfloor \frac{a_i}{K} \right\rfloor$ instead, with some fixed $K$. In this way you maintain the close-to-optimal ratio $a_1 : a_2 : a_3 : a_4 : a_5 : a_6$ but save a lot because the deck shrinks significantly.

I don't think that there is an analytical solution to such a problem, I would do some programming (and I suppose that the exact implementation does not belong to math.se): given a value of $a$ you know the optimal way to distribute it into $a_i$, and also optimal $a \le 147$, which leaves not that many choices

Comment: Also take a look at this [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827764/100-blank-cards-minimize-the-ev?rq=1).